# Inter-thread communication with Sockets without blocking methods

Tags: sockets, blocking, nonblocking

I now have successfully started the amount of threads I want to start for my vector clock test program. The next problem seems to be the inter-thread communication; the config files the threads read have a list of IP address (localhost) and port combinations and they should each start listening on the port given to them and at the same time read through the input file, which tells them to either increment their logical clock or send a message to a certain other thread.

If I first create ServerSockets for each thread, the accept() method will apparently block until someone tries to connect to this certain thread via a socket and meanwhile this thread cannot perform other actions that might've been instructed in the input file (which only has lines in the format ("int sendMessageTo int" or "int incrementClock k" - the integers represent lines in the config file, which contains the host & port listing). Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

On linux you can use `accept4` instead of `accept` and pass `SOCK_NONBLOCK` as the `flags` parameter.

On POSIX.1-2001, SVr4, 4.4BSD conforming system you can set `O_NONBLOCK` using `fcntl`.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to mention I'm using Java. I familiarized with SocketChannels and Selectors, but I still do not understand how I can listen to a port in a thread and at the same time do other stuff, such as sending a message to another thread, if no connections are required for this thread. With Selector, the select() again seems to block. The following might clarify my needs:
listen to a port portNumber; if no connections are requested, then continue reading the input file and act on it, while still maintaining readiness to handle incoming connection requests in the future.